# Looking for a term for $f \in O(1/n^{1+\varepsilon})$

Tags: asymptotics, terminology

$\renewcommand\epsilon\varepsilon$ I'm interested to know whether there is any established expression for $f \in O(1/n^{1+\epsilon})$ for $n\to\infty$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Basically I'm looking for the name for the set $$S = \bigcup\limits_{\epsilon > 0 } O(1/n^{1+\epsilon})$$ (or a way of saying that a function belongs to that set).

The key here is that saying $f \in O(1/n)$ is not sufficient, since $O(1/n) \supset S$. (Consider the example $f(n) = \frac{1}{n\log n}$. Clearly $f \in O(1/n)$ but $f\not\in S$.)

Is there a term for this? Or is there another better way of saying

- *"$f \in O(1/n^{1+\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon>0$"* or (equivalently)
- *"$f \in O(1/n^r)$ for some $r>1$"*?

Comment: I don't know of any such terminology, nor do I expect any term or special kind of notation. I think all of the ways you state $S$ are reasonably understandable. (Note the intersection should be a union however.)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks for correction! I wasn't really sure whether to expect a term for this, but I thought the condition was very close to the expression we get in the Dirichlet series of the Zeta function, where this is (on the real line) the condition for convergence. But it was probably a little bit far fetched:)